# RangeSlider not updating in Flutter Dialog Box

Tags: flutter

_currentRangeValues contains the range of slider.

The problem is, the slider is not updating when it is used even though set state method is also used.
Please help.

```
RangeValues _currentRangeValues = RangeValues(18, 60);
    
      dialog(BuildContext context) {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return Dialog(
              child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 300,
                child: RangeSlider(
                  values: _currentRangeValues,
                  min: 18.0,
                  max: 60.0,
                  divisions: 1,
                  labels: RangeLabels(
                    _currentRangeValues.start.round().toString(),
                    _currentRangeValues.end.round().toString(),
                  ),
                  onChanged: (RangeValues values) {
                    setState(() {
                      _currentRangeValues = values;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this example that I have created from the example that you provided.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SampleApp(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class SampleApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SampleAppState createState() => _SampleAppState();
}

class _SampleAppState extends State<SampleApp> {
  RangeValues _currentRangeValues = RangeValues(18, 60);

  dialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return StatefulBuilder(builder: (thisLowerContext, innerSetState) {
          return Dialog(
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 300,
              child: RangeSlider(
                values: _currentRangeValues,
                min: 18.0,
                max: 60.0,
                divisions: 1,
                labels: RangeLabels(
                  _currentRangeValues.start.round().toString(),
                  _currentRangeValues.end.round().toString(),
                ),
                onChanged: (RangeValues values) {
                  innerSetState(() {
                    _currentRangeValues = values;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Your heading'),
        ),
        body: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('press'),
          onPressed: () {
            dialog(context);
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

using the statefullbuilder for the dialog , Let me know if it works.

Comment: innerSetState method is not present

Comment: Did you check the above example there is a statefulbuilder as a child for showDialog. If you are stuck at any point edit and add  the code so that I can replicate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `StatefulBuilder` and set `divisions` property bigger than one like code below:

```
dialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, innerSetState) {
          return Dialog(
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 300,
              child: RangeSlider(
                values: _currentRangeValues,
                min: 18.0,
                max: 60.0,
                divisions: 10,
                labels: RangeLabels(
                  _currentRangeValues.start.round().toString(),
                  _currentRangeValues.end.round().toString(),
                ),
                onChanged: (RangeValues values) {
                  innerSetState(() {
                    _currentRangeValues = values;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
      },
    );
  }
```